# Closed formula for unconstrained (matrix) optimization problem

Tags: matrices, convex-optimization, matrix-calculus

Let $M$ be a square matrix of size $n$, $(a_i)_{i\in[1,n]},(b_i)_{i\in[1,n]},y$ vectors of size $n$ and $\lambda$ a real.

Is there a closed form for the following problem:

$$\arg\min_M \sum_i(y_i-a_i^TMb_i)^2+\lambda||M||^2_2$$

Where $||M||^2_2$ is the sum of squares of the elements of the matrix.

Comment: How about $M=0$.

Comment: In the case $M=0$, the value is $\sum_i y_i^2$

Comment: Oh, whoops, now I see.

Comment: Hint: It is just least squares with Tikhonov regularization.

Comment: @user251257 I am optimizing over M, it is harder (at least to me) than a genuine least squares over vectors...

Comment: $a_i^T M b_i$ is linear in $M$ and $\|M\|_2$ is the "euclidean" (frobenius) norm. Do you know how to solve least squares with Tikhonov regularization?

Comment: @user251257 Yes, I am familiar with linear regressions and penalized regressions, but not with this type of opitmization tasks

Comment: To make it more familiar looking: Let $\operatorname{vec}(X)$ denote the vector by stacking the columns of $X$ under each other. Then, $a_i^T M b_i = \operatorname{vec}(a_i b_i^T)^T \operatorname{vec}(M)$ and $\|M\|_2 = \|\operatorname{vec}(M)\|_2$.

Comment: @user251257 Nice rewriting, thanks ! If you don't plan to write the answer, I will

Comment: go ahead :) ${}{}$